# Is it possible to not trigger (page) event programatically in Paginator?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paginator

I would like to know if there is a way to not trigger the (page) event (and the method called with it) of paginator when using the method "this.paginator.nextPage()" ?

Something like the "{emitEvent: false}" of the "patchValue()" method.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you can use an auxiliar variable

```
flag:boolean=false;
```

And use

```
this.flag=true;
this.paginator.nextPage();
this.flag=false;

<paginator (page)="!flag && doSomething()"></paginator>
```